# db:migrate table not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

I am trying to create a table with 3 columns url, price and timestamps...I tried both "change" and "up"

```
class Shp < ActiveRecord::Base
  def change
    create_table :shps do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.float :price
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Running db:migrate seems to do nothing, as when I do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.column_names("shps")
```

I get a table with default columns only.

```
=> [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteColumn:0x8fc8a34 @name="id", @sql_type="INTEGER", @null=false, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:integer, @default=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteColumn:0x8fc878c @name="created_at", @sql_type="datetime", @null=false, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>, #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteColumn:0x8fc8444 @name="updated_at", @sql_type="datetime", @null=false, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @primary=nil, @coder=nil>]
```

Comment: You test with the method "column_names" the existence of `:shps` which is a table? Maybe you can check via other tools than Ruby (PGAdmin3 for PostGreSQL, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration classes should inherit from `ActiveRecord::Migration` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base`. They should also be placed in proper directory (`db/migrate`) and their filename should contain appropriate timestamp.

To generate migration among with model, you should type in your console:

```
rails g model Shp url:string price:float
```

and run migration:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

BTW for your own convenience try to make class names more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**app/models/shp.rb:**

```
class Shp < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "shps"
end
```

**db/migrate/2013xxxxxxxxx_create_shps.rb:**

```
class CreateShps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:shps) do |t|
      t.string :url
      t.float :price
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

HTH

Comment: Would both classes go in the same file?

Comment: of course not, as you are using Ruby on Rails, I suppose you know where to put them (edited original answer for clarity).